# How can I change the duration for an Android AnimationDrawable animation on-the-fly?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android platform.  I'm using the following to animate a set of 16 "frames" using AminationDrawable in my app:

**In the XML file I have:**

```
<animation-list 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_1" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_1_25" android:duration="200" /> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_1_5" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_1_75" android:duration="200" /> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_2" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_2_25" android:duration="200" /> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_2_5" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_2_75" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_3" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_3_25" android:duration="200" /> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_3_5" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_3_75" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_4" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_4_25" android:duration="200" /> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_4_5" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_4_75" android:duration="200" /> 
</animation-list>
```

**In the Java code I have the following**

first I'm declaring the class and adding an `onCreate()` method where I set up the animation.

```
public class MyNewActivity extends Activity 
{
    // member variables (accessible from within class methods below).
    AnimationDrawable mainAnimation;
    long mSpeed = 50;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_widget);
        // set up image
        ImageView mainImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_widget);
        mainImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animated_image);
        mainAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mainImage.getBackground();
    };
<...snip...>
```

...then later on I start my drawing when the user presses a button I call the following to start the animation moving:

```
private void start()
{
    // start the image rotating.
    if (mainAnimation.isRunning())
        mainAnimation.stop();

    int numFrames = mainAnimation.getNumberOfFrames();
    for (int ii = 0; ii < numFrames; ii++ )
    {
        // change the animation speed.
        Drawable d = mainAnimation.getFrame(ii);
        mainAnimation.scheduleDrawable(d, mainAnimation, mSpeed);
    }
}
<...snip...>
```

So elsewhere in the code I have a place to adjust the member variable `mSpeed`.  If I do this and then call `start()`, the animation will start, however the speed is always the same (essentially what was defined in the XML above.  My question is, how can I modify the "duration" of the frames to move this animation faster/slower based on user input?  I see no way to modify a "duration" state, and was under the assumption the `ScheduleDrawable()` call above would change the drawing's frames duration.

Comment: Good question. I don't see a way to do this from looking through the developer docs, but I'm interested to see the answer.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem but I managed to solve it when reading the [source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.java;h=e275ba8941dde04af7319a72646465cc1a9478da;hb=HEAD) of AnimationDrawable by implementing my own AnimationDrawable class that extends AnimationDrawable and override the `Run()` method and add `setDuration()` method which allows me to set the duration as follow:

By reviewing the original run method we see that it do the same but by calling `scheduleSelf(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + duration);` with the duration you specified when adding the frame so I changed it. I also add duration because I use the same for all my frames but you can use array of new duration.

```
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class MyAnimationDrawable extends AnimationDrawable {

    private volatile int duration;//its volatile because another thread will update its value
    private int currentFrame;

    public MyAnimationDrawable() {
        currentFrame = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int n = getNumberOfFrames();
        currentFrame++;
        if (currentFrame >= n) {
            currentFrame = 0;
        }
        selectDrawable(currentFrame);
        scheduleSelf(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + duration);
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
        //we have to do the following or the next frame will be displayed after the old duration
        unscheduleSelf(this);
        selectDrawable(currentFrame);
        scheduleSelf(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis()+duration);
    }
}
```

It's my first answer so I hope it helps you and it's explained well.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer so I can have more reputation to enter the chat.

Comment: How did you cast `AnimationDrawable` class to `MyAnimationDrawable`? 
I've got problem that object that is returned from `rocketImage.getBackground()` method. 
<!-- language: lang-js -->`
ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocket_image);
rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rocket_thrust);

rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();`

Any suggestions?

Comment: I was reading the images from memory so I created MyAnimationDrawable object and add frames programmatically then set it as ImageView drawable like this animDrawable = new MyAnimationDrawable();
int n = filesNames.length;
Drawable frame;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 frame = new BitmapDrawable(fileman.getImage(dir, filesNames[i]));
 animDrawable.addFrame(frame, 1000);
}
myImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(animDrawable);
animDrawable.setOneShot(false);
animDrawable.setDuration(speed);
animDrawable.start();