# how to change the duration of AnimationDrawable on the fly/runtime?

Tags: android-animation

Can anyone tell how to change the frame duration of AnimationDrawable on the fly/runtime/dynamically? I am having 25 frames in the AnimationDrawable i want to change the duration on seekbar progress change listener. with range of 100-80-60-40-20 means fastforwording the animation. please suggest!!!!

Answer (score 0):

see my answer to this question
[How can I change the duration for an Android AnimationDrawable animation on-the-fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371105/how-can-i-change-the-duration-for-an-android-animationdrawable-animation-on-the-f)