# Android: change "duration" attribute of animation-list programatically

Tags: android

I have code snippet to view gif image on imageView and it's working just fine but can anyone tell me how do i change duration  attribute (**android:duration="100"**) programatically. 
Here is the code : 
**move_forward.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/animation_list"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/forward_a"
        android:duration="100"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/forward_b"
        android:duration="100"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/forward_c"
        android:duration="100"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/forward_d"
        android:duration="100"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/forward_e"
        android:duration="100"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/forward_f"
        android:duration="100"/>

</animation-list>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.move_forward);
    }
     public void onClickPlay(View view) {
         AnimationDrawable startAnimationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
         startAnimationDrawable.start();
     }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the duration for an Android AnimationDrawable animation on-the-fly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371105/how-can-i-change-the-duration-for-an-android-animationdrawable-animation-on-the)

Answer (score -1):

have you tried [setDuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setDuration%28long%29) method of Animation class may be help you

Comment: Thnak you for replying. Can you be specific how to use setDuration with AnimationDrawable ? I mean how to convert the object of AnimationDrawable to animation and then use setDuration.

Comment: check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371105/how-can-i-change-the-duration-for-an-android-animationdrawable-animation-on-the) it will help you

Comment: Thnx for reply ,the above answer is generated from the same link and it works.

Comment: @Ranvijay asked how to change the duration of `AnimationDrawable`, not of the Animation class.  To be clear, native `AnimationDrawable` has no *setDuration* method; the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607129/5025060 works by extending `AnimationDrawable` with a custom *setDuration* method.