# How can increase/decrease duration of translate animation dynamically (on-the-fly)

Tags: android

In my app a large text in textview scroll up automatically with translate animation, and i designed two button for decrease and increasing speed, but when I change the duration it's work after last duration so it is not on-the-fly,  but I want whenever I clicked, in that moment duration changed.In fact I want to do like [how to change the duration of AnimationDrawable on the fly/runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371105/how-can-i-change-the-duration-for-an-android-animationdrawable-animation-on-the) ,but, with "Translation animation"

Comment: could you add some code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for randomly blinking light

```
    final ImageView imageLight = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageLight);
    lastLightAlpha = (float) Math.random();
    AlphaAnimation blinkLightAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, lastLightAlpha);
    blinkLightAnimation.setDuration((long) (Math.random() * 3000));
    blinkLightAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            float newAlpha = (float) Math.random();
            AlphaAnimation blinkLightAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(lastLightAlpha, newAlpha);
            blinkLightAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
            blinkLightAnimation.setDuration((long) (Math.random() * 3000));
            lastLightAlpha = newAlpha;
            imageLight.startAnimation(blinkLightAnimation);
        }
    });
    imageLight.startAnimation(blinkLightAnimation);
```

You can also reset your animation by

```
gearAnimation.cancel();
gearAnimation.reset();
```

I hope you can use parts of this code to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, this is not my my answer. I want to do something like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371105/how-can-i-change-the-duration-for-an-android-animationdrawable-animation-on-the) but with "translation animation"